# Parse text to correct json using Python TTP

Tags: python, json, parsing

Let's suppose that I have the text below:

```
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/1.1
 qinq stacking vid 10 pe-vid 100
 qinq stacking vid 20 pe-vid 100
 qinq stacking vid 30 pe-vid 200
#
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/2.1
 qinq stacking vid 20 pe-vid 200
#
```

I want to parse it using [Template Text Parser](https://ttp.readthedocs.io/).

This is the target JSON I want to get:

```
[
    {
        "subinterfaces": [
            {
                "interface": "GigabitEthernet1/0/1.1",
                "stacking": {
                    "100": [ "10", "20" ],
                    "200": [ "30" ]
                }
            },
            {
                "interface": "GigabitEthernet1/0/2.1",
                "stacking": {
                    "200": [ "20" ]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I tried this template

```
<group name="subinterfaces">
interface {{ interface | contains('.') }}
<group name="stacking.{{ pevid }}">
 qinq stacking vid {{ vid }} pe-vid {{ pevid }}
 </group>
# {{ _end_ }}
</group>
```

but it gives me that

```
[
    {
        "subinterfaces": [
            {
                "interface": "GigabitEthernet1/0/1.1",
                "stacking": {
                    "100": [
                        {
                            "vid": "10"
                        },
                        {
                            "vid": "20"
                        }
                    ],
                    "200": {
                        "vid": "30"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "interface": "GigabitEthernet1/0/2.1",
                "stacking": {
                    "200": {
                        "vid": "20"
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Any modifiers/functions applied to **vid** using "|" (pipe) do not have any effect.

**The motivation behind this question is to learn TTP mechanics. Please do not send answers with another tool.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that is interesting question, but there are no match variable or group function exists to satisfy this requirement of combining matches in a list while having several `{{ match }}` variables defined on a line. There is [joinmatches](https://ttp.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Match%20Variables/Functions.html#joinmatches) function exist, but it would not work here for that particular reason.

Best what I can think of is results post-processing using Python.

For instance this template defines `post_processing` Python function using macro tag and passes results through it using output tag:

```
<group name="subinterfaces">
interface {{ interface | contains('.') }}
 <group name="stacking.{{ pevid }}.{{ vid }}">
 qinq stacking vid {{ vid }} pe-vid {{ pevid }}
 </group>
# {{ _end_ }}
</group>

<output macro="post_process"/>

<macro>
def post_process(data):
    for item in data[0]["subinterfaces"]:
        item["stacking"] = {
            k: list(v.keys()) for k, v in item["stacking"].items()
        }
    return(data)
</macro>
```

`subinterfaces` group was modified to poduce these results:

```
[
    [
        {
            "subinterfaces": [
                {
                    "interface": "GigabitEthernet1/0/1.1",
                    "stacking": {
                        "100": {
                            "10": {},
                            "20": {}
                        },
                        "200": {
                            "30": {}
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "interface": "GigabitEthernet1/0/2.1",
                    "stacking": {
                        "200": {
                            "20": {}
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
]
```

after passing above data through outputter with `post_processing` macro, results transformed to desired structure:

```
[
    [
        {
            "subinterfaces": [
                {
                    "interface": "GigabitEthernet1/0/1.1",
                    "stacking": {
                        "100": [
                            "10",
                            "20"
                        ],
                        "200": [
                            "30"
                        ]
                    }
                },
                {
                    "interface": "GigabitEthernet1/0/2.1",
                    "stacking": {
                        "200": [
                            "20"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
]
```